# Add layout from different .js file to current window in Titanium

Tags: android, iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have multiple .js files and in each file I have a view

```
var view = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundImage : '/images/myiage.jpg',
    width : deviceWidth + 10
});
```

Then i create my Label's, TextView's, ImageView's  and add it to the created view.

```
view.add(label);
view.add(textview);
view.add(imageview);
```

How can i add this layout to my current window from a different .js file? For example when the user clicks a button i need to change my layout to a layout that is defined in a different .js file. But i don't now how to include te other .js file in the button click event.

I'm not using the alloy folder

Comment: put this code in a JS file and and use the common js functionalities like exports to expose a function and require that file in the your desired js file and call exposed function there.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to listen to a custom event on the first controller, then when your second controller detects the button press, fire off that event.

The other way would be pass around references to controllers between js files, which can easily end in tears later down the line.